# Expressing a probability as binomial coefficients

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Here's the problem: A box contains 21 working calculators and 4 defective calculators. Two calculators are drawn from the box with replacement. What is the probability that one calculator is functional and the other one is defective?

I was able to solve it using three approaches ($x$ is the answer):

1. Intuitively: $\frac{21}{25} \cdot \frac{4}{25} \cdot 2 = x$
2. Solving for $x$ in the sample space: $(\frac{21}{25})^2 +(\frac{4}{25})^2+x = 1.$
3. Using the binomial distribution: $\binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k} = \binom{2}{1}(\frac{21}{25})^1(\frac{4}{25})^{2-1} = x$

Now, that is nice and all, but what I'm really wondering how you can express a solution to this problem **in terms of binomial coefficients only** (or if that's even possible). For example, if I want to find the probability of drawing exactly one ace from a 5-card hand in a standard 52-card deck, then I would do: $\frac{{4 \choose 1}{48 \choose 4}}{52 \choose 5}$

Which comes from the general rule of probability: $\text{number of ways an event can happen}\over\text{total number of outcomes}$

Comment: So, just as with your cards, you'd take $\binom {21}1\times \binom 41\big/ \binom {25}2$.

Comment: Should say:  your first computation is incorrect.  It should be $\frac {21}{25}\times \frac 4{24}\times 2$.

Comment: Why is that? The two events are independent, right?

Comment: Oh, my error.  I didn't see that you said "with replacement".  My computations were both for "without replacement".  But in that case, you really aren't choosing two objects from a collection, so binomial coefficients don't arise in any obvious way.

Answer (score 1):

Ways the event can happen $= 2\cdot 21\cdot 4 = 168$

Total number of outcomes $ = 25\cdot 25 = 625$

Probability of the event $ = 168/625 = 0.2688$